# Sequelize add association

Tags: sequelize.js

I have an association set up like this:

```
m.User.hasMany(m.Interests, { joinTableName: 'user_interests', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
m.Interests.hasMany(m.User, { joinTableName: 'user_interests', foreignKey: 'interest_id' });
```

Sequelize is awesome in that I can just do user.getInterests. But how can I add a new association?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do either:

```
user.addInterest(interest)
```

To add a new interest, without changing the current ones, or you can do:

```
user.setInterests([interest])
```

The second option means associate *only* the interest I just gave you with the user, and remove any old associations if they exist.

https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/associations/

Comment: That's great. Great answer. Sequelize is awesome :-)

Comment: What is `interest` in this? An instance of `interest`? Or a query to find it?

Comment: Can be an instance or a primary key